# Square root of complex number in polar or rectangular form

Tags: complex-numbers, polar-coordinates

I am trying to find how to simplify:

$$\sqrt{\frac{A+jb}{C+jd}}$$

My calculator errors out, giving a math error, and I don't know how else to solve this.

Comment: [Please see here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/264) for a guide to writing math with MathJax, and [see here](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) for a guide to formatting posts with Markdown.

Comment: Is  $j=i$? or $j=\exp(2i\pi/3)$?

Comment: Sami, $j = i$ in certain engineering contexts, as I is current.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Soham, and others for your efforts, but here is a much straight-forward just pluck in the values [solution to my problem:](http://www.mathpropress.com/stan/bibliography/complexSquareRoot.pdf)

[image]

Comment: Thanks the both solutions. I guess camelbrush's answer needs to have a $\pm$ sign in both real and imaginary parts: \begin{align*}
\sqrt{a+jb}={}&\sqrt{|a+jb|e^{i(\mathrm{arg}(a+jb) + 2k\pi)}} = \sqrt{|a+jb|}e^{i\frac12\mathrm{arg}(a+jb)}e^{ik\pi} ={} \\
{}={}& \pm\sqrt{|a+jb|}e^{\frac i2\mathrm{arg}(a+jb)}.
\end{align*} **Note** I tried to guess what "phase" meant, and added a few $i$s I deemed to have been forgotten. Hope I got things right.

Comment: Oh. Didn't realize that **Note** was going to be converted too :). Ex-answer converted to comment, I edited it and left that note. If you're wondering why this commenter should be guessing about their own comment :).

Answer (score 3):

I understand you're trying to convert to polar.

Multiply top and bottom by $\overline{C-id}:$
$$\sqrt{\frac{(A+ib)(C-id)}{(C+id)(C-id)}}
= \sqrt{\frac{(AC+bd) + i(bC - Ad)}{C^2 + D^2}}$$

<s>Work from that!</s>
Let $z$ = the complex number $(AC+bd) + i(bC - Ad)$.

Then, convert $z$ to polar form:

Firstly, $\sqrt{(AC+bd)^2 + (bC - Ad)^2}$ can be simplified to $\sqrt{(A^2 + b^2)(C^2+d^2)}$.

The argument of $z$ is $$\tan^{-1}\bigg(\frac{bC-Ad}{AC+bd}\bigg)$$
Hence $z$ can be expressed as 
$$\bigg[\sqrt{(A^2 + b^2)(C^2+d^2)}\bigg]\exp\bigg({i\tan^{-1}\bigg(\frac{bC-Ad}{AC+bd}\bigg)\bigg)}$$

Therefore:
$$\sqrt{\frac{(AC+bd) + i(bC - Ad)}{C^2 + d^2}}$$$$
= \sqrt{\frac{\bigg[\sqrt{(A^2 + b^2)(C^2+d^2)}\bigg]\exp\bigg({i\tan^{-1}\bigg(\frac{bC-Ad}{AC+bd}\bigg)\bigg)}}{C^2 + d^2}}$$$$
= \exp\bigg({\frac{1}{2}i\tan^{-1}\bigg(\frac{bC-Ad}{AC+bd}\bigg)\bigg)}\sqrt{\frac{\sqrt{(A^2 + b^2)(C^2+d^2)}}{C^2 + d^2}}
$$$$
= \bigg(\frac{A^2 + b^2}{C^2+d^2}\bigg)^{1/4}\exp\bigg({\frac{1}{2}i\tan^{-1}\frac{bC-Ad}{AC+bd}\bigg)}$$

Fine enough?

Comment: I am trying to get rid of the root. Your suggested method still leaves me with a complex number under a root. other suggestions?

Comment: I believe Soham Chowdhury's answer would be an intermediate step. Once you have his expression, convert the inside of the square root to polar, and take the square root.

Comment: How does one take square root of angles? eg: how do I solve : $$\sqrt{A AngleB}$$

Comment: Check it out now.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

It suffices to know how to find $\alpha+i\beta$ such that $(\alpha+i\beta)^2=a+ib$.

Expand the last equality then solve for $\alpha$ and $\beta$ the equations:
$$2\alpha\beta=b\quad\text{and}\quad \alpha^2-\beta^2=a$$

Comment: Proposed edit from an anonymous user: "there is example in power system analysis by Glover,page 247"

Answer (score -1):

Simply, follow the steps:

$1.~$ express the complex number into polar form $~R<\theta$.

$2.~$ $\sqrt{a+jb} = R^{0.5} <\frac{\theta}{2}~$

i.e., magnitude $=$ power $\frac{1}{2}$
            angle $=$ product of $\frac{1}{2}$

$3.~$ Now again convert polar form to rectangular form.

Thank YOU !!!

Comment: Please use MathJax

Comment: Did you notice that this question has several answers, one of which was accepted?